# Android constants in attrs.xml

Tags: android

I see dimension constants declared in android attrs.xml (data/res/values/attrs.xml) such as

```
<attr name="padding" format="dimension" />
<!-- Sets the padding, in pixels, of the left edge; see {@link android.R.attr#padding}. -->
<attr name="paddingLeft" format="dimension" />
<!-- Sets the padding, in pixels, of the top edge; see {@link android.R.attr#padding}. -->
<attr name="paddingTop" format="dimension" />
<!-- Sets the padding, in pixels, of the right edge; see {@link android.R.attr#padding}. -->
<attr name="paddingRight" format="dimension" />
```

If I am correct, the value is defined in
`./data/res/values/styles.xml` as       `<item name="android:paddingLeft">20dp</item>` etc.

Are these some kind of "preferred" dimension values. Are these values relatively stable between release so that the apperance wont be affect if one directly use these constants.

Thanks.

EDIT:

To clarify a bit, I was wondering the implication of using the these "android" defined values in my view layout, like.

```
<TextView android:text="@string/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall"
    android:paddingStart="?android:attr/expandableListPreferredItemPaddingLeft"/>
```

Instead of me defining these values, I am referring it in the android namespace. Is it safe to do so?

Answer (score 2):

As you can create `Drawables` with different postfixes, `Layouts` with postfixes, you can create `values` directory by different postfixes like

```
values
values-large "or" values-sw600dp
values-xlarge "or" values-sw720dp
```

In this, you can create your constant. This will helpful while creating dynamic layouts.

Suppose you need to create a layout for normal screen and tablet, both requires different spacing. So what will you do? Create two different layouts? or simply add two entries in `values` directory?

Answer is `values` directory. Its efficient.

**Edit**

layout.xml

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_left">
```

And you have defined `margin_left` inside `values` and `values-sw600dp` directory like

```
<dimen name="margin_left">20dp</dimen>

<dimen name="margin_left">40dp</dimen>
```

respectively. This will give you lot more idea to create one `layout` and efficient handling.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if i correctly understand the question but if you use independent units like dp, dip, sp etc instead of raw values in pixels then it will be looking the same on different devices.
Here you can read about it: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html